# how to run tomcat as service and not use root user

Tags: tomcat

I copy catalina.sh to /etc/init.d/tomcat and sudo chkconfig --add tomcat
it started as root user,I want use another user,how?

Answer (score 6):

If you do want to create your own start up script for whatever reason. Then to run tomcat under another user use `su -c "$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat.sh start" nobody` when starting tomcat. (nobody is the user in this case that tomcat will start under)

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=455567

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* copy `catalina.sh` to `/etc/init.d/tomcat`. Ubuntu provides (in its `tomcat6` package) a `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` startup script that will invoke `catalina.sh` as the correct user.

Also, using `chkconfig` on Ubuntu is not supported; it's a script for Red Hat-based systems. Don't use it.